# Is there a way to suppress legend entry when plotting directly from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to do multiple plot operations on a Matplotlib axis `ax`. The data are in a pandas DataFrame, so it is natural to use multiple plotting commands:

```
df.plot(..., ax=ax)
```

But for some of those, I don't want a label entry in the legend. I have tried to add `label="_nolegend_"` but that does not work.

The only workaround I found is to first extract the data from the DataFrame, then plot them in a loop with individual `ax.plot` commands, adding a `label` parameter where I want it in the legend. This is tedious.

NOTE: I am not asking how to remove the legend altogether.

EDIT: After @Vitalizzare posted his nice answer (thank you!): Of course, I tried that because it's in the documentation, but it does not work in my case. It isn't easy to understand why, but I think it has to do with the number of curves plotted. Consider this code:

```
dg = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(400).reshape(10,40))
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
dg.iloc[1:8].plot(ax=ax,style='.-',color='lightgray',legend=False)
dg[[32,33]].iloc[1:8].plot(ax=ax)
```

Something very strange happens here. I get inconsistent results! Sometimes I get a figure with NO legend. I have no idea why. I am running mpl 3.5.1 and pandas 1.4.2. In my original notebook, I cannot get the correct behavior.

Comment: Could you show an example to see how it differ from the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid plotting a legend we can pass `legend=False` as a parameter to `df.plot`. To restrict the legend to the first N labels, we can run `ax.legend(list_of_labels_to_show)`. To show an arbitrary set of labels, we can plot the data separately in 2 steps on the same axes with `legend=False` on those which shouldn't be displayed.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,2],
    'y': [2,1],
    'z': [1.5,1.5]
})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(1, 4, subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'}, figsize=(12, 3))

fig.suptitle('Plotting data with')

ax1.set_title('full legend')
df.plot(ax=ax1)

ax2.set_title('first n legend')
df.plot(ax=ax2)
ax2.legend(df.columns[:2])

ax3.set_title('selected legend')
df[['x','z']].plot(ax=ax3)
df['y'].plot(ax=ax3, legend=False)

ax4.set_title('no legend')
df.plot(ax=ax4, legend=False)

fig.savefig('legend_example.png')
```

Output:

[image: legend example]

Comment: I do not think OP is trying to remove the legend entirely. To take the example in your answer, I think they want to be able to remove either `x` or `y` in the legend without removing the entire legend.

Comment: @JoshuaShew In this case we can do it in 2 steps. First, plot the data which should be in legend. Next, plot the rest of data with `legend=False` on the same axes.